# Apply changes automatically from one azure database to another

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I am trying to implement source control for database stored procedures. I am using Azure DevOps and I have added all the stored procedures to an Azure Repo.

I am connecting to the Azure Repo through the team explorer in SSMS. I am working on a branch and once the stored procedure changes are added to the master branch I want the changes to be automatically deployed to the production database.

Is this possible using an Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link has step by step instructions as to how we can set up Azure pipeline to execute the changes from one database to another:

https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/iac/200.2x-IaC-CDAzureSQLdbwithVSTSandVS.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with **[`DACPAC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)**

You can follow the following links,

Use tools that help you integrate and deploy your database along your code. Build better apps on any client OS (Windows, Linux, and macOS) using our graphical user interface and command line tools.

**[`DevOps using SQL Server`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/sql-devops/)**

**[`Continuous Deployment of SQL`](https://medium.com/modern-stack/continuous-deployment-of-sql-server-database-changes-using-visual-studio-tfs-release-manager-753b26c9cd1e)**